# How to use DejaVu Sans Mono in definition header?

Tags: fonts

I have this code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[scaled=0.9]{DejaVuSansMono}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}


\begin{document}
This is a test. \lstinline!Positive! set.

\begin{definition}[Positive]\ \\
  \indent A set $S$ is called positive if \ldots
\end{definition}

\end{document}
```

When I write `\begin{definition}[\lstinline!Positive!]` instead of `\begin{definition}[Positive]`, the definition header disappears. (LaTeX only shows the body of the definition.)

How to fix this?

Comment: Is there a real need for `\lstinline`? I can't see it, just `\texttt` suffices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```
 \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

before you load `dejavusansmono` and for your definition use:

```
 \begin{definition}[\texttt{Positive}]~\newline
```